# Default sender names for linux system accounts with postfix

Tags: postfix

When sending mails from system accounts postfix seems to use "([account name])" as the sender name. The [account name] itself is stored in /etc/passwd, so I could simply rename them, but the general layout with (...) stays.

Is there a good way to change this to a completely different schema for all system accounts? Something like "[server] [account name]"?

I am using postfix on Debian 9.